# Как сгладить SVG путь (кривую) в реальном времени?

Tags: javascript, svg, математика

При рисовании кривой по полученным координатам получаются просто соединенные прямые. Я посмотрел несколько алгоритмов, которые делают плавную линию как на гифке ниже, но все это происходит в пост обработке, когда пользователь закончил рисовать и уже тогда ломанная линяя превращается в кривую.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сделать плавную кривую в реальном времени как на гифке ниже? Catmull–Rom spline вроде делают что-то подобное, но кажется я не туда копаю. Есть ли стандартное решение данной задачи, чтобы не изобретать велосипед?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вызывайте алгоритм сглаживания во время рисования.

Comment: Какой алгоритм? Я же написал, что те алгоритмы сглаживания работают в пост обработке. Если их вызывать во время рисования, то линия будет постоянно перестраиваться и дергаться. Тот же алгоритм Шнайдера http://soswow.github.io/fit-curve/demo/ . Можете уточнить о какой алгоритме вы говорите, чтобы его можно было вызывать во время рисования?

Comment: Отличное демо. Есть над чем подумать.

Comment: А чем Катмул-Ром не угодил? У него будет проблем с дерганьем - он строит сплайны, где форма кривой зависит только от близких (хронологически) точек. Хороший вариант, как мне кажется.

Comment: Видимо его и буду использовать. Просто думал есть какое-то стандартное решение вроде библиотеки, так как почти все граф. редакторы используют очень похожее сглаживание (по крайней мере мне так кажется).